# Spartacus3.2- How to change sequence of Default page load API Call's

Tags: spartacus-storefront

User call is happening at end of page load. Is there any modules placed wrong? So that API call always last? Can I know How to call User API "https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8443/occ/v2/powertools-spa/orgUsers/current?lang=en&curr=USD" After Pages call
?

Is there a way to change default API's order?

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: hello there, is it possible to provide any concrete use case why the default API's order should be changed?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I am using Auth0 login with Spartacus3.2. Once I click on checkout page CheckoutAuthGuard is throwing error as by that time current API is not completed. user Information is not provided. So looking to change current call as second API call

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are accessing the cart page. Just try to see the sequence in your cart-details.component.ts. You might be having two observables cart$ and user$. Just try to see whats the execution order is on route change using the debugger. You will get to know what's causing the issue.

Alternatively, if you want to place a cart call after the user call, it's possible. You can put your cart call inside your user call. Use subscription to do that. But I don't see the point here to do that, because your API can get a currently authenticated user with "current" in the user id param.